# How to place glTF file in aframe?

Tags: html, aframe, gltf

I'm just trying to add a 3d model from Sketchfab into this scene, but I can't find any straightforward tutorials on how to do so. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Peachtree Corners Veterans Monument - A-Frame</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Peachtree Corners Veterans Monument!">
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://button.glitch.me/button.js"></script>  
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <a-scene>
            <a-sky src="https://cdn.glitch.com/0dd56231-cb65-46f8-ad38-225931845e77%2Fsky1.jpg?1528307112422"></a-sky>
        </a-scene>
        <div class="glitchButton"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the sketchfab model I want to upload:https://sketchfab.com/models/729e5bc464454b5099445538e7785a19#

Comment: I encourage to use 0.8.2. A lot has changed since 0.5.0

Comment: For A-Frame 0.7.0+ — https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/gltf-model.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the `gltf-model` component - there is an example in the [documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/gltf-model.html#example)

Download the zip from sketchfab, there are two files: `scene.gltf`, `scene.bin` and a `textures` folder, make sure they're in the same directory, and load the model:

```
<a-assets>
  <a-asset-item id="scene" src="/path/to/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>

<a-entity gltf-model="#scene"></a-entity>
```